# Is the set S linear independent?

Tags: linear-algebra

**Questions:**

> 1. If S $=$ {$a, b, c$} $⊆ R^3$, where $(2,3,4)$ $∉$ span {$a, b, c$}.
> 2. If S $=$ {$a, b, c$} $⊆ R^3$, where $(1,2,3)$, $(1,3,2)$, $(2,1,3)$, and $(0,1,0)$ $ϵ$ span {$a, b, c$}.
>
> Are the above set S linear independent?

**My thoughts:**

From what I know, linear independent means there is only one solution.

As for question 1, what i understood by this $(2,3,4)$ $∉$ span {$a, b, c$} is that $$(2,3,4) ≠ \lambda_{1} a + \lambda_{2} b + \lambda_{3} c $$ where $\lambda$ are real numbers. What then does this relation means?

As for question 2, I was thinking along finding any form of linear combination between the four vectors and if it exists $\implies$ they are no linear independent. Am i right to say that? If so, what is the best way to find linear combinations.

Thanks a ton.

Comment: Do you know about basis and dimension?

Comment: @paw88789, yes i learnt about them theoretically, but I do not understand the intuitive meaning of the concepts though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For question 1:

Since the dimension of $\mathbb{R}^3$ is $3$, a set of $3$ vectors is linearly independent if and only if that set spans $\mathbb{R}^3$.

For question 2:

You should be able to convince yourself, that $\{(1,2,3) , (1,3,2), (2,1,3),  (0,1,0)\}$ spans $\mathbb{R}^3$. And then so does $\{a,b,c\}$.  But again using dimension, this means that $\{a,b,c\}$ must be a basis for  $\mathbb{R}^3$, and hence linearly independent.